# How does CHIP 8 graphics rendered on screen?

Tags: javascript, chip-8

*Opcode DXYN:
Draws a sprite at coordinate (VX, VY) that has a width of 8 pixels and a height of N pixels. Each row of 8 pixels is read as bit-coded (with the most significant bit of each byte displayed on the left) starting from memory location I; I value doesn't change after the execution of this instruction. As described above, VF is set to 1 if any screen pixels are flipped from set to unset when the sprite is drawn, and to 0 if that doesn't happen.*

Basically I have an array called graphics which is a double array constructed out of 64 rows of new arrays per each with 32 columns.

```
//Creating new double arrays for storing graphics data
    graphics = new Array(GFX_WIDTH);
        for(var i = 0; i < graphics .length; i++){
            graphics [i] = new Array(GFX_HEIGHT);
            for(var j = 0; j < graphics [i].length; j++){
                graphics [i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
```

and inside these arrays, I am storing graphics data as described above. My question is, do I just have to draw a square when an array element is 1 and empty that space when it's 0? According to a blog article on CHIP8, there is an extra array for font-set but what's the usage of it?

The blog article I have mentioned above

http://www.multigesture.net/articles/how-to-write-an-emulator-chip-8-interpreter/

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, note that the pixels are bitpacked - each byte will contain 8 pixels of sprite data. In other words, the byte 0xAA is a single-pixel tall sprite with the first, third, fifth and seventh pixel set.

When drawing your sprite, you need to loop through each bit. If the bit is set, you *flip* the corresponding bit in your display - 0 becomes 1 and 1 becomes 0. This can, for example, be done by applying the XOR (^) operation to your display byte.

Note, however, that VF must be set to 1 if any pixels go from 1 to 0 in the process, and 0 if no pixels are unset - so you also need to do this. I find it is easiest to read if you have an if that checks whether or not to flip a bit, and then take care of both flipping and VF-updating inside that if.

For reference, my own Delphi implementation of this opcode looks like this:

```
procedure TChip8CPU.OpcodeD(inst: TInstruction);
var
  X, Y, cX, cY, data: byte;
begin
  Reg[$F] := 0;
  for Y := 0 to inst.NibbleArg - 1 do begin
    cY := (Reg[inst.Y] + Y) mod HEIGHT;
    data := Memory[AddressI + Y];
    for X := 0 to 7 do begin
      if (data and ($80 shr X)) <> 0 then begin
        cX := (Reg[inst.X] + X) mod WIDTH;
        if Display[cY, cX] = 1 then Reg[$F] := 1;
        Display[cY, cX] := Display[cY, cX] xor 1;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Note that for sprites which go outside the screen boundaries, they wrap around (this is done by the `mod WIDTH`/`mod HEIGHT` parts). This is mentioned in [Cowgod's Chip-8 Technical Reference](http://devernay.free.fr/hacks/chip8/C8TECH10.HTM#Dxyn).

Comment: Cheers, I forgot to select this answer. Your example code helped me. TA.. !